# Creating an Login Based To Do List Application in IOS using core data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am trying to build an IOS application that uses username and password to show the To Do List for the specific user using core data. So, far I have built the application that checks if the user exists and logins in the user. I also have completed the TO Do List. But, my problem is the any user can see all the To Do List if someone signs in created by every other use. How can I make it only visible to the user who created the to do list based on his/her sign in.  I am trying to achieve it using core data. It would be great if someone could show me how to do it or provide me links where there are examples. I have been stuck with this for few days. 
If there are any other ways to do without using core data, I would like to know but preferably I want to use core data.

I have two Entities Users and List. I have already created relationship to them. Here's the code that basically fetches everything from the List Entity.  How can I modify it to get the data only related to a specific user. I am not sure how to create unique ID and implement it. An example would be really helpful.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated   {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    //Create NSManagedObjectContext instance

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    //Code to fetch the request
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"List"];
    //Add to NSMutable array
    lists=[[context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil]mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData ];
}
```

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Set an unique ID for your user, and link it (relationship) to your "to do data" when you create it. When you search for "to do data", search only the one linked to this user.

Comment: use 2 entity, one for user & another for the To do things. Then relate them  like the 4th FAQ on this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFAQ.html .

Comment: Check request.predicate property and NSPredicate class in Apple documentation. Also you don’t need another unique ID as probably user login is (should be) already unique. Check [raywenderlich.com](http://raywenderlich.com) for tutorials.